# Ionic Accordion list issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular5

Im Create My `ionic 3`  mobile application for   `Ionic  Accordion` Accordion is working perfect, but I have some small issue . When I click the Accordionist list item after display  `toggleDetails` but i cannot click the  toggle Details Item. main list are closing, how to fix that issue, you can understand my issue please check that : [My Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-spenmx)

**ts**

```
export class SearchPage {
  data: Array<{title: string, details: string, icon: string, showDetails: boolean}> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
      this.data.push({
        title: 'Title '+i,
        details: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
        icon: 'ios-add-circle-outline',
        showDetails: false
      });
    }
  }
  toggleDetails(data) {
    if (data.showDetails) {
      data.showDetails = false;
      data.icon = 'ios-add-circle-outline';
    } else {
      data.showDetails = true;
      data.icon = 'ios-remove-circle-outline';
    }
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SearchPage');
  }

}
```

**html**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Ionic 2 Accordion Example.
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item padding *ngFor="let d of data" (click)="toggleDetails(d)"><ion-icon color="primary" item-right [name]="d.icon"></ion-icon>
      {{d.title}}
      <div *ngIf="d.showDetails">{{d.details}}</div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve it via just move `(click)="toggleDetails(d)"` from `ion-item` to `ion-icon` , like this :

```
<ion-item padding *ngFor="let d of data" >
    <ion-icon color="primary" item-right [name]="d.icon" (click)="toggleDetails(d)"></ion-icon>
    {{d.title}}      
    <div *ngIf="d.showDetails">{{d.details}}</div>
</ion-item>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-accordian-issue)**

Comment: Sir, understood , thanks for your solution and valuable time

Comment: @core114, Glad you got the idea, Happy Coding BTW :)